# sonar application initialization failed

Tags: initialization, sonarqube, failed-installation

I have unzipped the sonar(code review tool) and started by executing batch file on win 7 64 bit
when m hitting the url in mozilla :http://localhost:9000 m getting following error

*Application initialization failed: no !/ in spec
    from file:/D:/#Software/sonar-2.9/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.0.1.jar!/vendor/rack.rb:7:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038:in`require'
    from file:/D:/#Software/sonar-2.9/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.0.1.jar!/vendor/rack.rb:28:in `boot!'
    from file:/D:/#Software/sonar-2.9/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.0.1.jar!/jruby/rack/boot/rack.rb:10:in`Rack'
    from file:/D:/#Software/sonar-2.9/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.0.1.jar!/jruby/rack/boot/rack.rb:8:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063:in`load'
    from file:/D:/#Software/sonar-2.9/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.0.1.jar!/jruby/rack/boot/rack.rb:1:in `(root)'*

**is it the right procedure to install the sonar or do i need anything else to do.?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) installation for evaluation purposes (without enterprise database) is very easy. It worked for me as described in the [2 minutes tutorial](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes). Have a look at the [requirements](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) - you need Java of course.

This is the instruction:

1. Download and unzip the distribution.
   (Do not install the application in a directory starting with a digit.
2. Execute on Windows:
   `bin\windows-x86-32\StartSonar.bat`
   or on other platforms:
   `bin/[OS]/sonar.sh console`
3. Execute the following commands on your Maven projects:
   `mvn clean install`
   `mvn sonar:sonar`
4. Browse to `http://localhost:9000`
5. For administration features, default login/password is admin/admin.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem ,it is because I used "#" in my base directory name thats why while executing it was not getting the path to some dependencies.

I will suggest all not to use any special characters in installation directory name if it is not explicitly required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I've just had something similar on Sonar 2.13.1 on Windows 7

Never mind special characters, my problem was installing it in C:\Program Files\, installing it in C:\Dev\ fixed it.
Also, being Windows 7 I had to open up the permissions on the logs directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sonar log messages are too generic in some cases. You might need to change the log levels to DEBUG and check again. Few things to check from my experience

1. Correct JDBC Driver (For the DBMS,For JDK version)
2. If you are using a JDK make sure to set wrapper.xml param wrapper.java.additional.3 to server
3. In wrapper.xml  (Standalone setup) check the java commnand is set to the intended jdk
4. If you all ready have a schema set up from a older version (When upgrading) drop the schema before reinstalling
5. Make sure the  user `{sonar.jdbc.username:}` is the schema owner